# VS Code don't read break in if statement

Tags: python, break

In my code, VSCode don't read break in if statement when entered 0 and don't skip to last for loop.

My syntaxes are right, I debugged but it doesn't break out of the loop.

```
from contents import pantry, recipes


def add_shopping_item(data: dict, item: str, amount: int) -> None:
    """add_shopping_item Add a tuple containing `item` and 
    `amount` to the `data` dict.
    """
    # if item in data:
    #     data[item] += amount
    # else:
    #     data[item] = amount
    data[item] = data.setdefault(item, 0) + amount



display_dict = {}
for index,key in enumerate(recipes):
    display_dict[str(index + 1)] = key

shopping_list = {} 
while True:
    #Display a menu of the recipes we know how to cook
    print("Please choose your recipe")
    print("-------------------------")
    for key, value in display_dict.items():
        print(f"{key} - {value}")

    choice = input(": ")

    if choice == 0:
        break
    elif choice in display_dict:
        selected_item = display_dict[choice]
        print(f"You have selected {selected_item}")
        print("Checking ingredients...")
        ingredients = recipes[selected_item]
        print(ingredients)
        for food_item, required_quantity in ingredients.items():
            quantity_in_pantry = pantry.get(food_item, 0)
            if required_quantity <= quantity_in_pantry:
                print(f"\t{food_item} OK.")
            else:
                 quantity_to_buy = required_quantity - quantity_in_pantry
                 print(f"\tYou need to buy {quantity_to_buy} of {food_item}") 
                 add_shopping_item(shopping_list, food_item, quantity_to_buy)


for things in shopping_list.items():
    print(things)
```

I debugged.
Also I write pass instead of break, and intented for loop, it ran then. How can I run it with break ?

Comment: choice is a string, if you enter 0 in the input, choice will be `'0'` and not `0`

Comment: `choice` is a string. When comparing to zero, you may want to convert it to an integer: `int(choice) == 0`

Comment: Yes, the `input()` function always returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

Because the returning type of `input` is always `string`, you have to convert it to an `int` or compare it to a `string`. Either;

```
if int(choice) == 0:
    break
```

Or

```
if choice == "0":
    break
```

As per **DarkKnight** and **Matthias**'s comments; you should use the second option since you can enter a string that couldn't be converted to an `int`. This approach is more flexible because you can compare the input to a preselected `string` like "exit", "stop", etc.

Comment: Second option is better unless you're planning on managing a potential ValueError exception

Comment: But I love those!

Comment: If it is not a number you want to do calculations with, the variable should be a string.